# Passing session value from one app to the next

Tags: session-variables, hanami

I'm setting a session value in one app and it's not available in any other app once the redirect happens. It's available in the source app (the one where the value is set) though. Is this expected behavior?

I've inspected session IDs in the origin app and in the target redirected app and they are different. So how can/should I pass the session variables from one app to the next? I need this for setting the authenticated user and currently it doesn't work due to this behavior.

Kind regards

Seba

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was using different session secrets for each app. When using the same session secret, it works as expected.

Seba